# Yii2 url routing to get a string parameter

Tags: php, url-routing, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have a url like this

*http://localhost/yii2/category/my-custom-string-parameter*

I need to get the text **my-custom-string-parameter**

And I setup the rules like this

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    'category/<url:>' => 'category/view',
            ),
        ],
```

This always give me 404 error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace `'category/<url:>' => 'category/view',,` with `'category/<id:\w+>' => 'category/view'`

Routing to View need an id and to use a string use w+ not url:

Comment: Actually the part before the ":" is just the name that will be used to store the value in the GET variables. "url" is perfectly fine if that is a better name than "id". The regex behind the ":" is what needs to match and the OPs code didn't work because the regex was missing completely